# Azure Easy table send notification

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-sql-database, azure-notificationhub

We have a inhouse small application that has a Azure Easy Table with a list of orders.

I would like that when one-person changes anything in this table a notification is send to the other PCs running the application to update this item.

Is there any way to monitor the Easy table for changes and then send update notification, or change the .js file of the Easy Table to do something on update?